# Was anything created by the Maw installation used for the designers original purpose?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the Jedi Academy trilogy, Han stumbles into an Imperial research facility inside the Maw black hole cluster.  He was questioned by a scientist about the first Death Star, and she then reveals that the super weapons weren't originally designed for weapons.

Examples:

The 'World Devastators' were designed to go through asteroids and strip them of material and produce things.  We see them used on Mon calamari to build TIEs and other war machines.

The Death Star's super laser was supposed to be used on dead planets in order to mine them easily.

Was there anything to back this up? Was there any sort of mineral processing on the death star, or things like that in any of the EU novels?

Comment: To the contrary: "The Tarkin Doctrine called for rule of the galaxy through fear of overwhelming force, and recommended the creation of superweapons such as the Death Star to create terror of Imperial reprisal that would stifle any thoughts of rebellion." –[Wilhuff_Tarkin/Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wilhuff_Tarkin/Legends)

Comment: Whatever helps you sleep at night I guess...

Comment: @Mazura I believe Han said the same thing to the scientist.

Comment: Pretty sure she's the only one that deluded herself enough to think they weren't superweapons.

Answer (score 1):

Han raises this issue during his "debriefing". The scientist realises that she's been a teensy bit of a moral vacuum in helping to design these weapons of mass destruction for the Empire.

> The Death Star was supposed to be used to break apart depleted, dead planets to provide access to raw materials deep in the core. Right! Had she thought up that excuse afterward? The World Devastators were supposed to be immense wandering factories taking useless rubble and fabricating scores of valuable industrial components. Right! Tarkin had been with her during the immense pressure of her original training. She knew what the man was capable of.
>
> And the new Sun Crusher was— ”What?” Han had said, raising his voice so that it hurt her fragile ears. “What in all the galaxy could the Sun Crusher be used for other than to completely wipe out all life in systems the Imperials don’t like? You don’t even have a bogus excuse like rubble mining. The Sun Crusher has one purpose only: to bring death to countless innocent people. Nothing more.”
>
> [Jedi Academy #1: Jedi Search](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Search)

In canon we've now seen the entire functional lifespan of the Death Star 1, from its going online in *Rogue One* and its destruction in *A New Hope*. It doesn't do *any* mining.